# Optional bool parameters in mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, optional-parameters

Here's what I want to have:

```
 [GET("page/{id}/")]
    public ActionResult Execute(Guid id, bool x = false, bool y = false, 
                                         bool z = false)
```

The reason I want to have the bools optional is so I can later use this method like this:

```
return RedirectToAction<SomeController>(c => c.Execute(id, y: true));
```

Unfortunately when I try to build the solution I get these errors: "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments" and "An expression tree may not contain a named argument specification".

My question is: is it possible to do something like that with controllers? What about optional parameters in routing?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a model class instead.
Something like:

```
public class ExecuteModel
{
    public Guid id {get;set;}
    public bool x {get;set;}
    public bool y {get;set;}
    public bool z {get;set;}
}
```

and change your Action to:

```
public ActionResult Execute(ExecuteModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

and your redirect would become:

```
return RedirectToAction<SomeController>(c => c.Execute(
    new ExecuteModel{id=id, y=true}));
```